# Is "XBox Live Vision Camera" the same as "Kinect"?

Tags: xbox-360, kinect

I have a Kinect, and I recently encountered an older XBox Arcade game called Puzzle Arcade, which lists support for the "XBox Live Vision Camera".  I assume this was how camera support was listed before Microsoft unveiled Kinect, but I'm unclear if the two literally mean the same thing.  For my purposes I basically want to know if games which list features that require "XBox Live Vision Camera", can support those features if you have a Kinect camera.

Comment: I can't find anything _official_ on this, though some xbox forum posts, and this support article pretty much seem to indicate that it is not the same, nor will Vision games work with the Kinect instead: http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/kinect/live-vision-camera-and-kinect-sensor

Comment: XBox Live Vision Camera is something entirely different then the Kintect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, no.  The games that support the Xbox Live Vision Camera are not natively supported by Kinect.

In fact, the two don't play nice together at all, according to this [Microsoft support article](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/kinect/live-vision-camera-and-kinect-sensor).  The only crossover app appears to be Video Kinect, which can be used with either device.

Comment: How ridiculous of me to assume my camera could be used as a... camera.